# Проблема с CMake C++

Tags: c++, cmake

Здравствуйте, совсем недавно познакомился с CMake до этого работал с Make. И вот после моего краткого знакомство никак не могу линкануть библиотеку к проекту...

#### Структура проекта:

```
- \Dependecies
---- \Include
-------- \glfw
------------ \...
-------- \glew
------------ \...
---- \Libraries
-------- \glew32s.lib
-------- \glfw3.lib 
- \Sources
---- \main.cpp   
- CMakeLists.txt
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glfw\glfw3.h> // не существует этого файла, хотя в Include он находится

int main() 
{
     std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("FastEngine")

link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Include/)

set (SOURCES Sources/main.cpp)

set (LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Libraries/glfw3.lib
               ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Libraries/glew32s.lib)

add_executable (FastEngine ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries (FastEngine ${LIBRARIES})
```

Хочу отметить, что собираю все на Windows под VS. Надеюсь что кто-нибудь поможет мне с этим...

Comment: а лог ошибок приведите пожалуйста.

Comment: В `link_directories` вы указываете пути к папке с инклюдами.

Comment: должно быть `include_directories`, а не `link`, опечатка?

Comment: и пути в `#include` разделяются прямыми слешами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("FastEngine")

set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14 )
set( CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON )

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Include)

set (SOURCES Sources/main.cpp)

set (LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Libraries/glfw3.lib
               ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Libraries/glew32s.lib)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBRARIES})
```

Такой вариант определённо должен работать.